# dynamic programming reduction of brute force

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

A  emoticon consists of an arbitrary positive number of underscores between two semicolons. Hence, the shortest possible  emoticon is `;_;`. The strings `;__;` and `;_____________;` are also valid  emoticons.

given a String containing only(`;`,`_`).The problem is to divide string into one or more emoticons and count how many division are possible. Each emoticon must be a subsequence of the message, and each character of the message must belong to exactly one emoticon. Note that the subsequences are not required to be contiguous. [subsequence definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence).

The approach I thought of is to write a recursive method as follows:

```
countDivision(string s){
 //base cases
 if(s.empty()) return 1;
 if(s.length()<=3){
   if(s.length()!=3) return 0;
   return s[0]==';' && s[1]=='_' && s[2]==';';
 }
  result=0;
//subproblems
  genrate all valid emocticon and remove it from s let it be w
  result+=countDivision(w);
  return result;
}
```

The solution above will easily timeout when n is large such as 100. What kind of approach should I use to convert this brute force solution to a dynamic programming solution?

Few examples

```
 1. ";_;;_____;" ans is 2
 2. ";;;___;;;" ans is 36

Example 1.

 ";_;;_____;" Returns: 2 
 There are two ways to divide this string into two emoticons. 
 One looks as follows:  ;_;|;_____; and the other looks like
 this(rembember we can pick subsequence it need not be contigous):  ;_ ;|; _____;
```

Comment: Could you maybe share one input and expected output so it is clearer?

Comment: if I understood... could you simply find and store any point like ";;" and than split the string in any possible way based on the previous computed points?

Comment: Does all character of the string need to be used in the division?

Comment: @AnotherGeek yes we have to use all character

Comment: @Daniele the shortest possible emocticon is ;_; so ;; is not valid emocticon

Comment: @PrashantBhanarkar ";;" I mean between two emoticon...

Comment: This looks to be from this (long-finished) TopCoder contest: https://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=14010&rd=16551

Answer (score 2):

I'll describe an O(n^4)-time and -space dynamic programming solution (that can easily be improved to use just O(n^3) space) that should work for up to n=100 or so.

Call a subsequence "fresh" if consists of a single `;`.

Call a subsequence "finished" if it corresponds to an emoticon.

Call a subsequence "partial" if it has nonzero length and is a proper prefix of an emoticon.  (So for example, `;`, `;_`, and `;___` are all partial subsequences, while the empty string, `_`, `;;` and `;___;;` are not.)

Finally, call a subsequence "admissible" if it is fresh, finished or partial.

Let f(i, j, k, m) be the number of ways of partitioning the first i characters of the string into exactly j+k+m admissible subsequences, of which exactly j are fresh, k are partial and m are finished.  Notice that any prefix of a valid partition into emoticons determines i, j, k and m uniquely -- this means that no prefix of a valid partition will be counted by more than one tuple (i, j, k, m), so if we can guarantee that, for each tuple (i, j, k, m), the partition prefixes *within* that tuple are all counted once and only once, then we can add together the counts for tuples to get a valid total.  Specifically, the answer to the question will then be the sum over all 1 <= j <= n of f(n, 0, j, 0).

```
If s[i] = "_":
  f(i, j, k, m) =
    (j+1) * f(i-1, j+1, k, m-1)    // Convert any of the j+1 fresh subsequences to partial
    + m * f(i-1, j, k, m)          // Add _ to any of the m partial subsequences

Else if s[i] = ";":
  f(i, j, k, m) =
    f(i-1, j-1, k, m)              // Start a fresh subsequence
    + (m+1) * f(i-1, j, k-1, m+1)  // Finish any of the m+1 partial subsequences
```

We also need the base cases

```
f(0, 0, 0, 0) = 1
f(0, _, _, _) = 0
f(i, j, k, m) = 0 if any of i, j, k or m are negative
```

My own C++ implementation gives the correct answer of 36 for `;;;___;;;` in a few milliseconds, and e.g. for `;;;___;;;_;_;` it gives an answer of 540 (also in a few milliseconds).  For a string consisting of 66 `;`s followed by 66 `_`s followed by 66 `;`s, it takes just under 2s and reports an answer of 0 (probably due to overflow of the `long long`).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fairly straightforward memoized recursion that returns an answer immediately for a string of 66 `;`s followed by 66 `_`s followed by 66 `;`s. The function has three parameters: `i = index in the string`, `j = number of accumulating emoticons with only a left semi-colon`, and `k = number of accumulating emoticons with a left semi-colon and one or more underscores`.

An array is also constructed for how many underscores and semi-colons are available to the right of each index, to help decide on the next possibilities.

Complexity is `O(n^3)` and the problem constrains the search space, where `j` is at most `n/2` and `k` at most `n/4`.

Commented JavaScript code:

```js
var s = ';_;;__;_;;';

// record the number of semi-colons and 
// underscores to the right of each index
var cs = new Array(s.length);
cs.push(0);

var us = new Array(s.length);
us.push(0);

for (var i=s.length-1; i>=0; i--){
  if (s[i] == ';'){
    cs[i] = cs[i+1] + 1;
    us[i] = us[i+1];
    
  } else {
    us[i] = us[i+1] + 1;
    cs[i] = cs[i+1];
  }
}

// memoize
var h = {};

function f(i,j,k){
  // memoization
  var key = [i,j,k].join(',');

  if (h[key] !== undefined){
    return h[key];
  }

  // base case
  if (i == s.length){
    return 1;
  }

  var a = 0,
      b = 0;
  
  if (s[i] == ';'){
    // if there are still enough colons to start an emoticon
    if (cs[i] > j + k){  
      // start a new emoticon
      a = f(i+1,j+1,k);
    }
      
    // close any of k partial emoticons
    if (k > 0){
      b = k * f(i+1,j,k-1);
    }
  } 
  
  if (s[i] == '_'){
    // if there are still extra underscores
    if (j < us[i] && k > 0){
      // apply them to partial emoticons
      a = k * f(i+1,j,k);
    }
    
    // convert started emoticons to partial
    if (j > 0){
      b = j * f(i+1,j-1,k+1);
    }
  }
  
  return h[key] = a + b;
}

console.log(f(0,0,0)); // 52
```

Comment: IIUC, you're able to shed a factor of n from the running time and space complexities by noticing that the 3 parameters i, j and k *uniquely determine* the number of completed emoticons in a partition (the parameter I called m in my approach), so m doesn't need to be recorded in the state explicitly.  Very nice!  A minor point: Your `f()` seem to be computing answers for the *suffix* starting at i, so e.g. `j` would be best described as "j = number of accumulating emoticons with only a *right* semi-colon" (and similarly for k).

Comment: @j_random_hacker thank you for your comment! Regarding `j` and `k`, I think if we were to express `j` and `k` as arrays holding actual emoticons, we could see that when `j` is incremented, it corresponds with a new call with `";"` added to the `j`s; when `k` is incremented, it would correspond with `k` calls, each adding an underscore to one of the `k`s; and when `k` is decremented, it would mean `k` calls, each one with another `k` removed from that array. (I left out the conversion from `j` to `k` but I imagine you get the idea.)